# Instagram video in iframe - turn off autoplay

Tags: html, iframe, video, instagram, instagram-api

I'm pulling instagram videos (urls) from the api and displaying them within an `iframe`. All works but I can't get them to not autoplay on page load. Inspecting the source, there's a video element with the `autoplay` attribute but I can't (as far as I know) do anything about it programmatically.

Is there a way to achieve what I want? I've tried decorating the `iframe` with `autoplay="false"`, etc. with no success (I'm sure the video element takes precedence...).

Answer (score 0):

I've never dealt with Instagram before, but a quick Google search led me to this article: http://thenextweb.com/facebook/2013/10/11/instagram-longer-lets-users-disable-video-autoplay-small-important-step-towards-ads/. It's from 2013, but it seems that you can't disable the autoplay function.

From my knowledge. You can't disable video autoplay using and `<iframe>`, but you can if you use `<video>`.